# How to fix "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, open-uri

Super new to coding! I created a new project with `rails new`.

I'm trying to scrape a website, but I am getting an error `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pry'

def get_page
    link = "https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))
    #rest of code
end

get_page
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Ruby version? Working perfectly on 2.6.3

Comment: My bootcamp had us download 2.6.1. I'm still new to this so I'm not sure where to read up on versioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
link = "https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(link))
```

Just add the `URI`

Answer (score 2):

[`Kernel#open`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-open) opens a file, IO stream, or subprocess. It doesn't open a URI:

> ## open(path [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) → io or nil
>
> ## open(path [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) {|io| block } → obj
>
> Creates an IO object connected to the given stream, file, or subprocess.

[`OpenURI`](https://github.com/ruby/open-uri) is [used](https://github.com/ruby/open-uri#usage) by calling the [`URI::open` method](https://rubydoc.info/gems/open-uri/URI%2Eopen):

> ## Method: URI.open
>
> `.open(name, *rest, &block)` ⇒ `Object`
>
> Allows the opening of various resources including URIs.

So, your code should look like this:

```ruby
def get_page
  link = "https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(link))
  #rest of code
end
```