# How to fix Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://jobs.lever.co/stackadapt

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to scrape a website using this tutorial:

https://towardsdatascience.com/job-board-scraping-with-rails-872c432ed2c8

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ3T9.jpg

Comment: What error and what is the code that produces that error?

Comment: This is the error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ3T9.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(link))
```

Added URI.

[This post helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605458/how-to-fix-errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-rb-sysopen?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Did you have the line:

```
  require 'open-uri'
```

before the `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL))`?

open-uri enhances the `Kernel.open` method, which normally only reads from a local file, with a http option. Your error looks like, open-uri was not loaded.